# idiom that describes similar characteristics

Tags: idiom-requests

I'm trying to remember a particular idiom you would say to someone when you feel that that person bares a remarkable resemblance to another person or group in terms of their behaviour or mindset. "You are ? from the same ?".

Its not "cast of the same mold". I think the verb is something like cleft/split/taken/grown. It might have an agricultural context, like "two peas in a pod".

Answer (score 1):

Cut from the same cloth! I was so sure it was something to do with wheat or some grain.